# Check if id exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:

Keywords structure:

```
domain_id | keyword_id | keyword | user_owe_id

test.com  |    4       |   test  |      1
```

Rankings structure:

```
domain_id | rank 

test.com  | 2
```

How i return rows only from same domain_id and where user_owe_id = 1

I mean like: "select * from rankings where user_owe_id = 1"

and user_owe_id is coming from keywords table so i mean i want to get results only where user_owe_id = 1 from keywords

how i check if the same domain_id have user_owe_id = 1 from keywords?

Comment: ^^vote down on questions board lmao..

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect it was because the question shows almost no research into basic SQL. That's one of the suggested reasons for voting something down. People are free to vote up or down as they wish, regardless of whether it's a question or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a basic `join`.

```
select *
from
    Keywords
    inner join Rankings on -- JOIN the tables. INNER filters to matches only
        Keywords.domain_id = Rankings.domain_id -- You can add more with AND
where Keywords.user_owe_id = 1; -- Put non-JOINing filters here
```

Comment: Thanks god you answer me :),now i know how to translate it to PropelORM Question,i tick as answered.

Answer (score 0):

can you see if this statement returns what you want

```
select * from rankings r, (select * from keywords k where user_owe_id=1 limit 1) tol 
where r.domain_id=tot.domain_id
```

Comment: Why would you default to an unnecessary messy subquery instead of a simple ANSI `join`?

Comment: Because if I have understood correctly he wants only one row form the keywords table, keywords table can have multiple user_owe_id with Id=1 and same domain_id.

Comment: "How i return rows only from same domain_id and where user_owe_id = 1" - I don't read this as including a requirement for 1 row only. - next - "i want to get results only where user_owe_id = 1 from keywords " - that "result**s**", plural, to me implies there is no desire to restrict to 1 row only. Besides, your proposal would filter to a single row using an unpredictable and unreliable order, since you haven't sorted - so even if the OP _did_ want to only keep 1 row, this might not give them the right one.

Comment: "how i check if the same domain_id have user_owe_id = 1 from keywords" I thought this sentence means that I want only one row from table keywords.  Yes, you are right my proposal will filter to a single row, but I have not read anywhere that he wants specific row of rankings table, what I understand was that I want to just one row from rankings and keywords where user_owe_id=1  and I do not care which row from the keyword table is. Maybe I am mistaken and I have not understood well

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

**Check out the working fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69ab0/5**

```
select r.domain_id, r.rank from Rankings r 
       inner join Keywords k on k.domain_id = r.domain_id 
where k.user_owe_id = '1';
```

Comment: The OP said "How i return rows only from same domain_id and where user_owe_id = 1". Assuming I'm reading that correctly, `left join` does not satisfy the "only" part of that, since it will return all rows from `Keywords`, even those that do not have a match in `Rankings`. But I might be misinterpreting.

Comment: Yes you are right, it should not be `left join`. but `inner`